# Use custom property from application.yml in static/index.html springboot webapp

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot web-application. resources/static folder is generated using `ng build` from an independent angular project.

In **application.yml** I want to specify **google map key** and want to use the same in resources/static/index.html script tag while importing the googlemap plugin

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${api.google}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing"></script>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: add a configuration endpoint to your backend and get your config from there.

Comment: @AmirSchnell Can you be more specific, I dint understand. I tried using thymeleaf. But since I want the change in index.html and its in static folder, its not working

Comment: I could not find anything particular on the web, that solves your problem. A workaround would be to create an endpoint in your backend, that sends a configuration object upon calling. In this configuration object you could put your google map key and other configuration related stuff. Call this endpoint once your website is loaded and store the config ina session wide context or cache or where you please.

Comment: using the key i need to load the js plugin, which need to be loaded when my application loads. By end point u means to say I should create a rest which returns this key and then use the key and load the scrip ?

Comment: But I want the script to be loaded and ready when my page loads

Comment: then you would have to create a build step, which modifies the source files and inserts the key before packaging them, but I really don't know how to do this sorry